# How to make a new column for a date index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a new column for a date index . Here's my dataset

```
 score          <80   80-100
 data
 2018-01-01      3        5
 2018-01-02      6        3
```

Here's the characteristic

```
In [150] df.columns

Out[150] CategoricalIndex(['<80', '80-100'], categories=['<80', '80-100'], ordered=True, name='final_score', dtype='category')
```

and

```
In [151] df.index

Out[151] Index([2018-01-01, 2018-01-02],
         dtype='object', name='date')
```

I want to convert index to a column like, what I've try is

```
df['date'] = df.index
```

But, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `reset_index` + `rename`

```
df.columns=df.columns.astype(str)
df.reset_index().rename(columns={'data':'date'})
Out[575]: 
score        date  <80  80-100
0      2018-01-01    3       5
1      2018-01-02    6       3
```

Comment: Error Message :`cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `df.set_index()`

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Error message: `cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`